# Do webcams from Microsoft/Oker support manual exposure? (How about other cheap webcam?)

Tags: video, camera, webcam, video-capture

How about Microsoft lifecam HD 3000, Oker u210, Logitech HD Webcam c525?

Any other brand/model are welcome. Please specific brand/model.

Did you test it on Windows before?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some webcam capabilities listed [here](http://alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/DirectShowCaptureCapabilities/Data). You are interested in "exposure", e.g.:

> Video
>
> Device: Microsoft LifeCam HD-5001
>
> [...]
>
> IAMCameraControl
>
> [...]
>
> - CameraControl_Exposure: -6, flags 0x02; -11..1, step 1, default -6, cap flags 0x03

`CameraControl_Exposure` is [explained on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318253).

You can check your own device caps and/or post it using this tool: [Enumeration of DirectShow Capture Capabilities (Video and Audio)](http://alax.info/blog/1531).